# Delete Contacts via REST API Using Postman in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, marketing-cloud-connect, contact-deletion

Trying to setup a way to delete contacts from a synched data extension via REST API.

It's from the connector pulled from a CRM object. Connection has been paused, there is no way to delete it directly from the instance that I know of so would like to try to delete it via REST API and see if it's possible to delete on the backend.

Any suggestions on how to pull this off for a synched. DE?

Answer (score 1):

Marketing Cloud provides a [Contact Delete Framework](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5) that will help here. This is available both via the UI and the API. Be sure to review the [Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_best_practices.htm&type=5).

Note the comment at the bottom around Synchronized DEs:

> For Synchronized Data Sources, delete the information from the original data source in Sales Cloud, Service Cloud, or another cloud. This deletes the corresponding record in the Synchronized Data Extension, but it doesn’t delete the contact record from Marketing Cloud.

As far as REST API goes, there are two options [Delete by Key](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByContactKeys.htm) or [Delete by ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByContactIDs.htm) to accomplish the second portion of that comment to delete the Contact record.

If you're a Postman user, my team manages a [collection of API calls](https://api.mcexperts.ninja/) you can pull from that includes both of these.